# Proving determinant with variables

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a problem that asks:

Prove that det$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 && 1 && 1 \\ 
a && b && c \\
a^2 && b^2 && c^2 \end{pmatrix} = (c-a)(c-b)(b-a)$

I was thinking of solving it like normal and see if I can end up with $(c-a)(c-b)(b-a)$

What I did:

det$\begin{pmatrix}
b && c \\
b^2 && c^2 \end{pmatrix}$ - 
det$\begin{pmatrix}
a && c \\
a^2 && c^2 \end{pmatrix}$ +
det$\begin{pmatrix}
a && b \\
a^2 && b^2 \end{pmatrix}$

which gives

$(bc^2 - cb^2)-(ac^2-ca^2)+(ab^2-ba^2)$

which simplifies to

$(b-a)c^2 + (a-c)b^2 + (c-b)a^2$

and this is where I got stuck. Am I even approaching this problem correctly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which simplifies to $\;\; (b-a)c^2 + (a-c)b^2 + (c-b)a^2$

Hint: $\;(b-a)c^2 + (a-c)b^2 + (c\color{red}{-a+a}-b)a^2\,=\,\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

It might be useful to look for helpful column/row operations before expanding.

Here, subtraction of the first column from the second and the third one simplify the determinant considerably:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} 
1 && 1 && 1 \\ 
a && b && c \\
a^2 && b^2 && c^2 \end{pmatrix} = 
\det \begin{pmatrix} 
1 && 0 && 0 \\ 
a && b-a && c-a \\
a^2 && b^2-a^2 && c^2-a^2 \end{pmatrix} = \ldots $$
$$ \ldots =(b-a)(c-a)\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 \\
b+a && c+a \end{pmatrix} = (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$$

Answer (score -1):

If a=b, b=c, c=a then determinant value is 0 so
  (a-b)(b-c)(c-a) are factor of the determinant now comparing the leading coefficient so the Value of the determinant is (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)